# How to prevent AWS execute-api VPC endpoint blocking other accounts API gateways?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

weird functionality with AWS execute-api VPC endpoint and wondering if anyone has found a workaround?

Let's say there is a lambda function running inside VPC and it has API gateway pointing to it. On top of that, VPC has execute-api VPC endpoint with private DNS enabled, so that the API gateway DNS name returns the internal IP instead of public IP.

Above works fine but the downside is that now it prevents us connecting to some other AWS accounts API gateway as all the api-gateway subdomains are now resolving to internal IPs?

Any workaround on this?

Comment: Also found this issue, did you ever find a more reasonable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find any solution, so decided to create yet another VPC where execute-api VPC endpoint is not enabled and moved external connection components into that VPC.